# Find a set A of rational numbers that is isomorphic to sup{$\omega$, $\omega^\omega$, $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$, $\cdots$}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Find a set *A* of rational numbers such that (*A*, $\le_Q$) is isomorphic to sup{$\omega$, $\omega^\omega$, $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$, $\cdots$}.

This is a question that is listed in *"Introduction to Set Theory"* by Hrbacek and Jech on page 123. Here, $\omega$ represents for the ordinal corresponding to the set of natural numbers. The prior question was to find such a set that is isomorphic to $\omega^\omega$, and I've constructed *A* as {$\prod {{1} \over {p_i^{a_i}}} $} there, where $p_i$ represents for the $i$th prime number and $a_i$ being its exponents.

Honestly, I've tried my best but couldn't construct such a set corresponding to sup{$\omega$, $\omega^\omega$, $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$, $\cdots$}. And now I have another question: what is the biggest ordinal number that is isomorphic to (*A*, $\le_Q$) where $\le_Q$ denotes the usual ordering in rational number? According to Well Ordering Principle, we know that *Q* can be well-ordered, then (*Q*, $<_W$) is isomorphic to a unique ordinal, but clearly $\le_Q$ isn't a well ordering. Is there no limit in this procedure?

Comment: your $A$ is totally not isomorphic to $\omega^\omega$

Comment: @mercio I thought it was, but now I think it is just $\omega^2$, am I right? @ Miha Habič Thanks so much! Embarassing that I couldn't have found it. I've checked the answer, but it uses 'the normal form' and actually the chapter is right behind this question. So I'm now wondering if there is any other way to prove this without using it.